# BGR555 Java Encoding

Tags: java

I'm developing a Java application which has to decode and encode BGR555 color format.

The decode procedure works like this:

```
short rgb;
int r,g,b;
r=(num & 0x001F) * 0x08;
g=((num & 0x03E0) >> 5) * 0x08;
b=((num & 0x7C00) >> 10) * 0x08;
```

The problem is when I want to encode starting from r,g,b values.
I'm not an expert on bitwise operations and I searched for tutorials on the web, but I didn't understand :(

My question is how to do this? What's the opposite of & and how to concatenate values?

Comment: What should be your input and output? As I understand, you need to convert 3 color values (red, green, blue) to one value BGR555, and the same backwards?

Comment: Yes, that's it. The problem is how, given R, G and B, return the BGR555 value

Comment: But are you sure that you're converting rgb to bgr555 properly? Could you please give a link, from where you got your code?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/tinke/wiki/NCLR

Comment: Yes I'm decoding it properly because the colors are correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution!
Here is the snippet:

```
public static byte[] fromBGR555(Color[] p) {
        ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(p.length * 2).order(
                ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
        for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
            int num = 0;
            num += (p[i].getRed() / 0x08);
            num += ((p[i].getGreen() / 0x08) << 5);
            num += ((p[i].getBlue() / 0x08) << 10);
            b.putShort((short) num);
        }
        return b.array();
    }
```